# How to get a link to edit an item in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I(HR) want to send an email to the employee with the link to edit his details i.e the newly added item in the SharePoint list. I'm actually copying the data into a new list and want to send a link to edit the new list rather than the previous list. Unlike Microsoft flows I'm not able to send a link to edit the list in SharePoint manager. I want to use only sharepoint manager to create the workflows

I've tried all the fields provided in the lookup and none of them actually gives me an edit link. I'm using SharePoint Online with SharePoint Designer 2013. Could someone tell me how it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the item ID based on output guid, so you could concat the string as edit form.

Demo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Lee_MSFT. I got the idea eventually and i agree it was a silly question but thanks for taking the time and answering my question